# How to properly format a list of quotes

Tags: grammar, quotations, lists

I have an article that contains a list of negative responses to a change in design for a milk jug. I want to use their feedback as a way to enforce my point that people don't like change. I am not a very good writer and think the way I worded it sounds awkward. Is there a better way to go about it?

**My sentence**
Things like “‘I hate it’ said Lisa ... ‘It spills everywhere’ said Amy ... ‘It’s very hard for kids to pour’ said Lee” were just a few of the responses consumers gave on the change.

**The original article**
"I hate it," said Lisa DeHoff, a cage owener in a Sam's Club here.
"It spills everywhere," said Amy Wise, a homemaker.
"It's very hard for kids to pour," said Lee Morris, who was shopping for her grandchildren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to not use the ellipses (...) to join the quotes. Perhaps, try to integrate it in your sentence.

You could write: `In response to the new handle, some people claim they "hate it" and say that "it spills everywhere" and that it is "very hard for kids to pour."`

For more information on how to integrate quotes into your writing, you can look at this resource:

http://academics.smcvt.edu/writingctr/Quotes.htm